# Mount a SSHFS volume into a Docker instance

Tags: ssh, docker, mount, sshfs, fuse

I use SSHFS to mount a remote filesystem on my host and I want to be able to access it from inside a Docker container.

I mount the remote filesystem

`sshfs -o idmap=user,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g) user@remote:directory /path/to/sshfs`

And, using Docker, I get the following errors depending on me using `--mount`:

```
docker run  -it -v /path/to/sshfs:/target myimage bash
docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/path/to/sshfs': mkdir /path/to/sshfs: file exists.
```

or `-v`:

```
docker run -it  --mount src=/path/to/sshfs,target=/target,type=bind  myimage bash
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /path/to/sshfs.
See 'docker run --help'
```

Is it possible to mount a sshfs mountpoint into a container?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Requires the following steps:

1. uncomment `user_allow_other` in `/etc/fuse.conf`
2. unmount the FUSE filesystem
3. remount the FUSE filesystem with `sshfs -o allow_other user@....` (making sure to include the `-o allow_other` option)
4. try starting the container again

Comment: Thanks! I did as you said and then mounted with `sshfs -o allow_other` and it worked!

Comment: Great, it works fine for me, even without the `-o allow_other` option added

Comment: If you cannot use `-o allow_other` because `user_allow_other` isn't set and you're not allowed to change that, you might find my answer below helpful: Instead of mounting your directory, mount its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Detailed step by step with external references:

1. Create and copy an SSH key to the remote server

Only need to do this the first time we make a SSHFS mount. [Here's an example on how to do this in ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-22-04).

2. Mount the Remote File System(s) Over SSHFS

[Follow the steps from this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh).

3. Mount a SSHFS volume into the Docker instance

`docker run  -it -v /path/to/sshfs:/target myimage bash`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but couldn't use "allow_other", as I have no root permission. But what I found out is, that you can mount the mount-point's parent.

So your example would work for me like this:

```bash
docker run  -it -v /path/to:/target myimage bash
```

Of course it's then not avalable as `/target` but only as `/target/sshfs`.